# Creating an letter/number ID from the date using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA

Lets say I entered the date: 2022/05/31 I would like to generate AE31

Where A represents the year,
E represents the month and
31 represents the date

How could I generate this ID data in excel using VBA?

Comment: Why 'A'? Why 'E'? How can we help if there is no further information. Let us know what your issue is and include your current code for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2):

That could be:

```vb
TheDate = DateSerial(2022, 05, 31)
ID = Chr(Year(TheDate) - 2022 + 65) & Chr(Month(TheDate) - 1 + 65) & CStr(Day(TheDate))

ID -> AE31
```

Comment: I have no idea if that's what the OP is after, but I'm upvoting for figuring out an answer that works from so little information.